# Transform vision msgs array from sensor coordinates to world coordinates

Tags: ros2, tf2, tf2-ros

I want to transform a detectionarray3d msgs from sensor coordinates to world coordinates. I know the transform function of the tf2 library, which should fulfill this step.

```
tf_buffer_->transform<vision_msgs::msg::Detection3DArray>(pose_in_, pose_out_, "world",
                tf2::Duration(std::chrono::seconds(1)));
```

Is it possible to use Detection3DArray msgs with transform function? because with this setup I am not able to build the package.